# Can anyone explain in detail the following two commands regular expressions

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

The following two commands used to count no of non-zero integers of second column in the text file. Can anyone please explain the regular expression in detail.

```
grep -c '^[^,]*,[^0][^,]*,' < myfile.txt
sed '/^[^,]*,0,.*/d' < myfile.txt | sed -n '$='
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first regex searches for any line containing the following:

```
'^        - start of line, followed by
 [^,]*    - 0 or more non-comma characters, followed by
 ,        - a comma, followed by
 [^0]     - any single character other than a zero, followed by
 [^,]*    - 0 or more non-comma characters, followed by
 ,'       - a comma
```

grep -c counts the number of matching lines

The second regex matches

```
'/        (the start of the regex)
 ^        - start of line, followed by
 [^,]*    - 0 or more non-comma characters, followed by
 ,0,      - a comma then a zero then a comma, followed by
 .*       - 0 or more other characters
 /d'      (the end of the regex -- delete the lines matching the preceding expression)
```